# Font-family style is not working in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jsp

```
Style="font-family: CoHeadlineBd, Arial;"
```

It's working fine in `Mozilla & Chrome` but coming to `IE` this is not effecting on the text.

Comment: are you using an @font-face rule to download the non-standard font?

Answer (score 0):

The font I see in your style is I think a non-standard font and so you will be needing to add a `@font-face` CSS rule to define it. Here you can see on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) how to make `@font-face` rules for internet explorer.

One thing more, try adding `quotes` around your font.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a webfont you will need to upload the font files and link to it or use @import in your CSS to get it from a CDN. For example

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Meie+Script);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8yRp/